# Cantor normal form to compute sums and products of ordinals: $\omega^{\beta} c+\omega^{\beta'} c' = \omega^{\beta'}c'$ if $\beta'>\beta$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

From Wikipedia on [Ordinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic):

> The Cantor normal form also allows us to compute sums and products of ordinals: to compute the sum, for example, one need merely know that
>       $$\omega^{\beta} c+\omega^{\beta'} c' = \omega^{\beta'}c' \,,$$
>   if $\beta'>\beta$ […]

Is this trivial? Can someone explain it? I don't see it yet.

Comment: Hint: It suffices to consider the case that $\beta' = \beta+1$.

Comment: $\omega^\beta c+\omega^{\beta+1}c' = \omega(\omega^{\beta-1}c+\omega^\beta c')\stackrel{\text{ind}}=\omega\cdot\omega^\beta c'=\omega^{\beta+1} c'$ – is this legal for ordinals?

Comment: What if $\beta$ is a limit? Then $\beta -1$ is not defined.

Comment: Do I just need to deal with this extra case or should I try a completely different approach?

Comment: @akkarin: $\omega^\beta\cdot c+\omega^{\beta+1}=\omega^\beta\cdot c+\omega^\beta\cdot\omega=\omega^\beta\cdot (c+\omega)=\omega^\beta\cdot \omega= \omega^{\beta+1}$, since $c$ is finite. And $c'\ge 1$, so $\omega^{\beta+1}\cdot c'=\omega^{\beta+1}+\omega^{\beta+1}\cdot(c'-1)$.

Comment: All right, I understand now that $\omega^\beta c+\omega^{\beta+n}c'=\omega^\beta\left(c+\omega^n c'\right)=\omega^\beta\omega^n c'=\omega^{\beta+n} c'$ for any finite $n$. But what if $\beta'$ is a much much bigger (limit or successor) ordinal? Why does $\beta' = \beta+1$ suffice? I can't "inductively" assume $\omega^{\beta'} = \omega^{\beta+1} + \ldots$.